# Poco FTPClientSession remote path

Tags: ftp, poco-libraries

I'm attempting to write files to a server in my program. I'm using FTPClientSession, everything is going well, I have a session started, it's logged in with no errors, I have a file I know is on my local disk but it fails to send the data as I think the remote path for the location it's trying to write to is always wrong no matter what I try.

I don't really know what the path should be, if I right click on a directory within filezilla I will get something like

ftp://"username"@ftp."subdomain".vhostall.com/public_html/

is that what I use? Or would I use

www."subdomain".vhostall.com/public_html

or if the client session already knows the domain, should I just use

public_html

(none of these work by the way). I always get an error message wihin an exception "STOR command failed: 553 Can't open that file: No such file or directory"

Comment: i've tried running a php script on in my server <?php echo __FILE__;?> which showed me the root path of the directory, I thought it would be "/home/domain name/public_html" but it was "/home/ftp username/public_html/" both of which don't work either

Comment: it's working now, it was just "/public_html/" that I needed. for some reason ostringstream remoteOSS; remoteOSS << remoteFolder << fileName; added garbage to the end of the string.